# Trying to understand CSS & Box-sizing : Border-box property

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, padding

I found a new style today while taking a class on Responsive Web Design, and then I looked up w3schools example and I'm slightly confused.

If I create a div of 200px by 200px and apply a 1px border around it, the element in total changes to 202px by 202px in theory.

But if I then apply border-box, it remains at 200 by 200 with the border and the actual content box is now technically 198px by 198px.

Just want to make sure that is what actually happens.

Using [the example from w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_box-sizing), you can see that `.div4`'s content doesnt seem to align properly however, why is that?

Answer (score 1):

When you apply `box-sizing: border-box;` and make a specific width, that width is the max width of your div, including border, padding (for padding is that you see in `.div4`), etc.

[image]

That great for responsive design because it help you to calculate width for adapt your design.

Comment: I thought thatadding padding: 50px adds it to all four sections of the element - top, bottom, left, and right. Maybe thats the real question I have then

Comment: padding:50px DOES add padding to all 4 sides.  Even in the w3schools example.  Although the height is fixed at 100px, so you can't really see the bottom padding there.  And you'll need to add longer text to see the right side padding.

Comment: @MichalMcCaskle you gave the div a fixed height of 100px, and 50px + 50px + text height > 100px. Remove the fixed height and you'll see the div stretch to accommodate for the 50px padding. Or add some more content and you'll see it overflow the div.